# Have Clonezilla in one LiveUSB partition, while leaving remaining space for image files

Tags: usb, partitioning, clonezilla

I have a 128 gig USB drive I want to use as both a Clonezilla Live USB, and also for the storage of images.

im deploying windows 10 - already got a sysprepted image (thanks for the advice though)

Comment: https://clonezilla.org/fine-print-live-doc.php?path=./clonezilla-live/doc/10_LinuxLive_USB_creator/00-create-clonezilla-live.doc shows how to create a LiveUSB w/ Clonezilla. Once you have done that and verified it works, resize the partition with the image and create a new partition (ext4, exFAT, NTFS, or your alternate filesystem). If you will please click [edit] and specify your primary computer's OS, the steps in an appropriate partition editor could be found for you.